# Python3: for-loop does not start

Tags: python-3.x

i have the code below and my problem is the third for-loop doesn't start.  This part should compare ids in history file with ids from json_result list and then download or not. What do i do wrong and how to fix it?

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d.%m')
for day in var.red_letter_days.keys():
    if today == day:
        api = AppPixivAPI()
        api.auth(refresh_token=var.refresh_token)
        json_result = api.search_illust(f'{var.red_letter_days[today]}', search_target='partial_match_for_tags')
        with open(var.history_file, 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for idx, illust in enumerate(json_result.illusts):
                for i in f.readlines():
                    if i == illust.id:
                        print(illust.id)
                        break
                    else:
                        f.write(str(i) + '\n')
                        download(api, idx, illust)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We cannot help you figure out what's wrong with your code if we don't have enough information to reproduce your problem. In this case, we don't know what `var` or `json_result` is, so there's no way we can tell you why your loops don't start. Please provide a [mre] that people can use to reproduce your problem. Since you're new here, please also take the [tour], and read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: Have you checked that `json_result.illust` is not simply empty?

Comment: yes, i've checked it, and everything is going ok except described issue

Comment: Do you mean the second for-loop, or the third for-loop?

Comment: yeah i'm sorry, i meant the third for-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've opened the file in append mode, with the `'a'` option (the `'+'` part opens for reading and writing, but it's still opened in append mode). This means the file is opened at the *end* of the file, so data can be appended. Reading from the end of a file will result in nothing, so `f.readlines()` will be empty, and `for i in f.readlines()` will be an empty loop.